# angular js $http post with laravel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, laravel-5

**Problem**

When I try to POST data I get error. For sure I do something wrong, also im new at angular. When I do GET all work fine, but Im not sure how to do POST.

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('createListController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http',
    function($scope, $log, $http){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/lists',
            data: $scope.name
        })
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    <label>List name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Type list name" />
    <button type="submit" ng-model="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary form-control">Add list</button>
</form>
```

**Laravel rout.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
    Route::get('lists', 'ListsController@index');
    Route::post('lists', 'ListsController@store');
});
```

**Laravel middleware**

```
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since'
        );
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Laravel kernel.php**

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
}
```

**Attempted to solve with**

```
myApp.controller('createListController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http',
    function($scope, $log, $http){
        if ($scope.submit == true){

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/lists',
            data: {name: 'text'}
        })

        .success(function () {
            console.log('true');

        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log('false');
        })
        }

    }]);
```

But it's not working too. I don't know what I do wrong and how to post data right..

**Error message**

Error from console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8888/lists. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access.

**Question**

How do I solve this error and get angular js $http post with laravel?

**My opinion**

I think there is something wrong in angular controller, it can't get data from form or something like that maybe.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: just to say, you should put your actual http request in a service/factory and then call it in your controller

Comment: Error from console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/lists. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

false

Comment: What is domain of the page you are sending your request from?

Comment: Im using xampp: http://localhost/angular/#/create

Comment: If you have a solution, please post that as an answer, instead of putting it in the question. Then by marking your own answer as accepted, you can mark your question as resolved (so others know your problem is solved!)

Comment: Ok, just make account there. I done it, but cant mark it 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I got solution by my self.
At 1st I make my angular controller work properly :

```
myApp.controller('createListController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http',
    function($scope, $log, $http ){

          $scope.addList = function () {
            var list = {
                name: $scope.listname
            };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists',
            data: list
        })

            .success(function () {
               console.log('true');
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log('false');
            })
    }

    }]);
```

At 2nd I set ng-model parameter to input text and ng-click parameter to button:

```
<label>List name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="listname" class="form-control" placeholder="Type list name" />
<button type="submit" ng-click="addList()" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary form-control">Add list</button>
```

At 3rd with POST method domains can't be different (at least in angular), so I don't use localhost:8888, but use full path localhost/folder/.. and it worked for me. Now I can POST data from frontend to backend.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Laravel, but you'll need to add OPTIONS request to your rout.php, not just GET and POST.

Because you say that GET works, but not POST, I would think that it's an issue with simple and pre-flight requests. POST turns out to be a pre-flight request because Angular by default uses `application/json` as data type. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) about pre-flight requests:

> It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.

So either transform your POST data to be urlencoded, or have the server respond to OPTIONS requests as well. Which is a better way because you'll probably need pre-flight for one reason or another.